# How can I pass JSON object for iOS push notification

Tags: java, ios, json, apple-push-notifications, javapns

I am using javapns for sending push notification to iOS devices and there two method normally used that is alert() and payload(). Using any one of this function we can send push notification to iOS device. Here for I need to pass json object instead of sending a simple message inside any one of these methods. So please can anyone tell me how I can achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Push. payload(........)` method instead, it needs `Payload` object.

```
String rawJSON = "{\"aps\":{\"alert\":\"Message received from Bob\"},\"acme2\":[\"bang\",\"whiz\"]}";
Payload payload = new Payload(rawJSON);
//Or as mentioned in the comments
PushNotificationPayload payload = PushNotificationPayload.fromJSON(rawJSON);
```

example of json is

```
{
    "aps" : { "alert" : "Message received from Bob" },
    "acme2" : [ "bang",  "whiz" ]
}
```

For payload json [The Notification Payload](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW1)

For [javapns docs read here](http://javapns.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/javadoc/index.html)

Comment: Thanks, thanks a lot. Can you please make it more clear how to create json string because I have facing problem while creating json string.

Comment: Thanks for editing your answer and now I got it how to create json string but here is another problem I am facing while I write the code Payload payload = new Payload(rawJSON); here I got the error message like ''Cannot instantiate the type Payload ". Thank you.

Comment: I don't know much about it as I just checked the docs and found this constructor. You have to sort it out. Also I have never used javapns.

Comment: Ok thanks and I sort it using the following constructor PushNotificationPayload payload = PushNotificationPayload.fromJSON(rawJSON);

Answer (score 0):

Ignore How default paypload is being created by APNS.newPayload.

Create your custom payload like this.

```
JSONObject requestedData = new JSONObject();
requestedData.put("id", 1);
requestedData.put("firstName", "K");
requestedData.put("lastName", "Joshi");

JSONObject aps = new JSONObject();
aps.put("alert", "KJ sent a message");
JSONObject request = new JSONObject();
request.put("aps", aps);
request.put("requestedData", requestedData);
//Create Payload
String payload = request.toString();
//Push
apnsService.push("deviceid", payload);
```